# HP Pavilion Pentium 3825U, HP "430" i5-6200U, Win 7-8.1-10 network/ethernet driver fails, PXE is fine

Tags: networking, drivers

We have a herd of computers running under Jenkins control. We have a Clonezilla/DRBL server that can reimage them as needed. I've seen a pattern recently of HP laptops with Intel processors that cannot maintain ethernet connections when Windows 7, 8.1 or 10, are running. They PXE boot fine, and download complete OS images, but once they boot Windows, the Network stops working and the yellow triangle /!\ appears on the desktop icon.

Could the problem be that I need to put the HP version of the Network/Ethernet driver into the images we're loading? Why would it work in live Ubuntu during imaging but fail under Windows? We didn't see this problem 6 months ago.

(update from Q&A below)

Question) When you run "troubleshoot network connection" on one of these machines, what does it tell you about the reason it can't connect fully? – Adam Wykes yesterday

answer- I ran "troubleshoot network connection" on the 3825. It's on Win7, It ran, then reported "Local Area Connection 2 doesn't have a valid IP configuration." And offered 3 ways to reset the switch / router. Below that, it offered to confirm when I thought the IP Configuration was good.

I moved the network cable for this computer from a heavily used Cisco router/switch to second Cisco router / switch I just put on this subnet. It was the 3rd connection on the new, 50 channel router / switch. I clicked to confirm, it passed. As I moved more cables to the new router, 3825 failed again.

Question) Is your windows install set to use DHCP for address assignment? What's the IP of the machine you tested? Is everything cool with your IPAM if you have one? – Adam Wykes yesterday

answer- Pent. 3825U computer is running ethernet at 100MBPS. Cat 6 wire and 1G switch, but the light on the switch doesn't lie. And the status of the ethernet port says 100.0 Mbps right now.

Yes, DHCP enabled. Our Clonezilla server has assigned 192.168.222.27 for this node on an internal network.

DNS server set to 139.95.250.235. AMD.com, where I work.

When the network connection breaks, first the IP changes to 169.254.220.218, and then the DNS changes to 
fec0:0:0:0fff::1x1,   fec0:0:0:0fff::2x1,   fec0:0:0:0fff::3x1

Additional Detail)  Put Win10 on Pent. 3825. Network up, looked good. After some time, went down. ipconfig /all reports the Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address as 100.254.63.108(Prefered). They're all (Prefered), even when they change suddenly. So Win10 isn't the magic fix here. Alas. – Bill IV

Question)  What install method did you use to get Win10 on that machine? 
– Adam Wykes

answer-  We have a Clonezilla server, run DRBL (Diskless Unbuntu) on the target system to use Clonezilla to restore a disk image on the target machine, then reboot. It has worked well for the 16.5 months I've been here.

Comment: When you run "troubleshoot network connection" on one of these machines, what does it tell you about the reason it can't connect fully?

Comment: Is your windows install set to use DHCP for address assignment? What's the IP of the machine you tested?  Is everything cool with your IPAM if you have one?

Comment: What install method did you use to get Win10 on that machine?

Comment: Read the answer you've received.

Answer (score 1):

The key clue here is that your IP address changes to an APIPA address when it breaks, which means that for whatever reason, this machine has lost contact with its DHCP server and decided to try to come up with an IP address on its own (http://searchexchange.techtarget.com/definition/Automatic-Private-IP-Addressing).

It is not likely your driver, since the NIC in your machine appears to be functioning exactly like it should. My suspicions lie strongly with your client network configuration on the gold image you pushed out, or else with the DHCP server itself in how it expects to see these machines once they connect.

Final hunch: given that you say "DHCP and our Clonezilla server has assigned 192.168.222.27 for this node on an internal network" I think we are a little confused about whether the address has been assigned as a static address or given out automagically by the DHCP server. Since APIPA has come into effect, I suggest setting the NIC to use the above IP address statically, then assign it the appropriate subnet and gateway data as well and reboot. If this fixes the problem then it is because your network is trying to communicate only with IP addresses it has assigned statically, and Windows is trying to get an IP address dynamically assigned, which isn't going to happen because your DHCP server has been specifically asked not to do that.

Also, check to make sure no other machine on the network is already using that IP address. I like to use `arp-scan` for that.